# How to disable zooming with scroll in OpenLayers2

Tags: openlayers-2, zoom

I am trying to disable the scroll zoom functionality in OpenLayers.
I have tried different things but nothing works.
First I tried this:

```
map.addControl(new OpenLayers.Control.Navigation({'disableZoomWheel':true}));
```

But nothing happened.
Then I found [this here](http://www.stoimen.com/blog/2009/06/20/openlayers-disable-mouse-wheel-on-zoom/) and I tried it but didn't work either. Actually in this case the page doesn't even load anymore.

Any ideas what to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you deactivate the navigation control that gets added to the map by default? If not so than you still have a navigation control with activated scroll wheel zoom.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are referring to OL3 and not OL2. You need to use [ol.interaction.MouseWheelZoom](http://openlayers.org/en/v3.3.0/apidoc/ol.interaction.MouseWheelZoom.html?unstable=true). I'm not exactly sure, but you might just be able to do `ol.interaction.MouseWheelZoom.active = false;` or you may need to bind to a specific event with something along the lines of `ol.interaction.MouseWheelZoom.on('zoom', function () {});`

Comment: Given the use of OpenLayers.Control, I'd say the question is about OL2.